# Enable custom error message in JSP through Java

Tags: java, html, jsp, servlets, materialize

I am currently working with JSP, Java servlets.

I am adding custom error messages for a form, I am following the example found on this site http://materializecss.com/forms.html under 'Custom Error or Success Messages'. What I want to do is once the user submits information it gets processed through a java servlet, if the Java servlet find an error with the users input, I want to enable the red error line that appears when an invalid input is entered.

The code I currently have is

```
 <input type="email" name="email" id="email" value="${param.email}" class="validate">
 <label for="email" data-error="Invalid Email" data-success="">Email</label>
```

Each email address has to be unique, so if the email entered is a valid email address then the user would submit the form, and when processing through the java servlet it would find that the email was already used and it will cause the `<label>` in the jsp page to turn red once the page reloads.

Comment: I'm not sure what the underlying question is. How to send the message? How to do validation? How to set classes using view-layer values?

Comment: How to make the line(<label>) under the text input area red using Java

Comment: Use a view value as a conditional, or the name of a class if it's semantic enough, and add a class to the label? I don't know enough about how materializecss works, but if it has an error class or JS that knows about validation that should be enough to get you going. Or if its validation can make an Ajax request then make a request to check the email. (Note that you should still validate on the server side.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to the question is that on the server side (java servlet) I would pass data into an argument

```
request.setAttribute("emailError", "error with email");
```

and on the client side (JSP) I did:

```
<input type="email" name="email" id="email" value="${param.email}" class="validate" <c:if test="${ not empty emailError}">style="border-bottom: 2.5px solid red; "</c:if> >
<label for="email" data-error="Invalid Email" data-success="">Email</label>
```

And if you wanted to also display the message from the Java servlet you could add

```
title="${emailError}"
```

to the input tag. This would create an additional message box to display the error message.

With this code, if a error is found on the server side, a message would be set and once the JSP page reloads the input line would be red indicating that an error happened.